# Setting the image to multiple screens in android

Tags: android

I have developed an **application in android**. In that I have kept a **background image** for each page. When I run that application in emulator the **layout is looking fine**. But when I installed that application in Samsung galaxy Apollo mobile phone **the image is stretched** **with the size of the mobile screen**. Also my application should run also in **Android Tablet**. So what should I do to overcome this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In *res/layout*, Say you have ***xmlLayout.xml*** which has

```
<ImageView 
    .
    .
    .
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundimage" />
```

Create folder *res/layout-large* and copy ***xmlLayout.xml*** into this folder

Edit the `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView 
    .
    .
    .
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundimage_large" />
```

Of course you should add to your *drawable* folder backgroundimage_large

---

[For more info, check the Android Developer: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9patch image as your background. A NinePatchDrawable graphic is a stretchable bitmap image.
The Draw 9-patch tool offers an extremely handy way to create your NinePatch images.
This tool comes with android sdk.Once you make your 9patch image it will automatically adjust in various screen size.
You can also find plenty of 9 patch images [Here](http://android9patch.blogspot.com/)